# Finding horizontal tangents

Tags: calculus

Find all values of $x$ for which the curve $y = (x^2/4)^x$ has horizontal tangents.

My attempt

$$y'= (x^2/4)^x (\ln(x^2/4) + 2)$$

$$0 = (x^2/4)^x (\ln(x^2/4) + 2)$$

How do I solve for $x$?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assuming your derivative is correct, note that a product is zero if and only if at least one of the factors is zero.

Comment: Yes and since (x2/4)x can never be 0, I assumed that ln(x2/4)+2 = 0. However, ln(x2/4) = -2, can't be a negative number.

Comment: @Tom Why not? If $x^2/4\lt e$, its logarithm is negative.

Comment: You can easily plot this function in Google, as well as the derivative (just type in the expression you want to plot). From that you can see there are horizontal tangents at about $x = \pm 0.7357$. The exact values are $\pm 2/e$ from your formula.